# asp.net (VB) countdown timer that is persistent through postbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a button and a label on my asp.net vb page and when the button is pressed I need a countdown timer to begin with 10 mins and update every seconds, 09:59, 09:58, 09:57 etc.... I need the timer to continue to countdown despite any postbacks or temporarily redirecting to a different page.

So far I have tried using Asp.Net Timers (With Async triggers/update panels) but for the seconds to countdown this needs to do a 1 second postback and is going to be quite resource expensive when there are hundreds of users accessing the system. It currently writes the exact countdown time to a session variable which is then retrieved when the page is reloaded - This is a very ugly method but they only way I can get it to work.

**Update - I have found the solution to my problem:**

Using this great Javascript Countdown Script http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js

**ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="jsTimeMarker"/>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.jss"></script>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="10 Mins" ID="btn10Mins"/>
```

**Code Behind Page:**

```
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Set Countdown Timer based on if Cookie is set
        If Not Request.Cookies("CountDownTimer") Is Nothing Then
            TimeMarkerRender(Request.Cookies("CountDownTimer")("Data"))
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub TimeMarkerRender(TargetDateTime As String)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    'sb.Append("TargetDate = ""08/28/2013 18:11:29"";")
    sb.Append("TargetDate = " & "'" & TargetDateTime & "'" & ";")
    sb.Append("CountActive = true;")
    sb.Append("CountStepper = -1;")
    sb.Append("LeadingZero = true;")
    sb.Append("DisplayFormat = ""%%M%%:%%S%%"";")
    sb.Append("FinishMessage = ""Finished"";")
    sb.Append("</script> ")
    jsTimeMarker.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub btn10Mins_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn10Mins.Click
    Response.Cookies("CountDownTimer")("Data") = Now.AddMinutes(10).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show you code. what you have tried?

Comment: The approach you are making sounds similar to what I would do, although maybe not use `Session` and instead use `ViewState`.

you could probably then get away with using javascript to count down, although if this is for an online exam you may not want to use javascript as a user could disable this.

Comment: @Secret Squirrel - Its not for an online exam - The user presses the button when they answer a telephone call. They need to know when the 10 mins is up so they can terminate the call. I have never done anything with ViewState before - do you have any examples?

Comment: @Subhash - Code Sample added

Comment: Here's the approach I would take: When they click the button, calculate the expiration time. Save that to a cookie. Every time the page loads or after a postback, check for the cookie and get the previously set expiration time. To do the actual countdown, [this jquery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) seems pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I mean the basic problem, as you've discovered, is that persisting it though any sort of postback is going to difficult and not as accurate.  Can you either use an iframe for your content page and have the counter running in javascript on the outside page or can you launch a new window with the counter running while your user is working?

Here is a simple countdown timer in javascript:
https://mindgrader.com/tutorials/1-how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: I cant use an IFRAME or a new window as it needs to be on the main page. I like the countdown timer in your link and @Jason P idea of setting a cookie

Answer (score 1):

**Update - I have found the solution to my problem:**

Using this great Javascript Countdown Script http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js

**ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="jsTimeMarker"/>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.jss"></script>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="10 Mins" ID="btn10Mins"/>
```

**Code Behind Page:**

```
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Set Countdown Timer based on if Cookie is set
        If Not Request.Cookies("CountDownTimer") Is Nothing Then
            TimeMarkerRender(Request.Cookies("CountDownTimer")("Data"))
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub TimeMarkerRender(TargetDateTime As String)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    'sb.Append("TargetDate = ""08/28/2013 18:11:29"";")
    sb.Append("TargetDate = " & "'" & TargetDateTime & "'" & ";")
    sb.Append("CountActive = true;")
    sb.Append("CountStepper = -1;")
    sb.Append("LeadingZero = true;")
    sb.Append("DisplayFormat = ""%%M%%:%%S%%"";")
    sb.Append("FinishMessage = ""Finished"";")
    sb.Append("</script> ")
    jsTimeMarker.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub btn10Mins_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn10Mins.Click
    Response.Cookies("CountDownTimer")("Data") = Now.AddMinutes(10).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great work! Thanks. 
Just one thing: you have a typo, it should read countdown.js instead of countdown.jss